# How does Channel Arcana combine with Channel Divinity from another class

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, cleric, unearthed-arcana

The Theurgy Tradition for a Wizard ([Non-divine Faithful, Unearthed Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA%20Non-Divine%20Faithful%20SFG.pdf)) has a feature called Channel Arcana that allows the character to use two options: Channel Divinity and Divine Arcana and works identically to Channel Divinity in the Cleric class.

How do these two differently named class features combine in a multi-class Wizard(Theurgy)/Cleric character?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The multi classing rules state (PHB p164):

> If you already have the Channel Divinity feature and gain a level in a class that also grants the feature, you gain the Channel Divinity effects granted by that class, but getting the feature again doesn’t give you an additional use of
>   it.

Therefore, RAW, the character gets both the Channel Arcana uses from the Wizard class and the Channel Divinity uses from the Cleric class as they are different class features. Even though Channel Arcana allows the use of a channel divinity option it is not Channel Divinity itself.

This is clearly very powerful, a work-around the multi-class rules put in place to limit the number of channel divinity options that can be used by a single character between short rests.

The obvious house rule is to treat them both as Channel Divinity for uses under the multi-class rules, even though Channel Arcana also allows Divine Arcana which is not a technically a Channel Divinity option.

I have no experience of running such a character so this is all theoretical.

Comment: to your "this is clearly a very powerful..." point, that's why UA come with the disclaimer they do =)

Answer (score -2):

## They aren't supposed to meet

Unearthed Arcana [is not tuned for multiclassing](https://www.twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/818875701881278464). Doing so puts you out of the playtest domain and into your own homebrew territory. If you're not capable or willing to homebrew your own material, you shouldn't allow multiclassing UA.